# How can I tell how much storage space my console has?

Tags: xbox-360

I have an older Xbox 360 with Kinect but need to work out how big the hard drive is. I no longer have the original box. Can anyone tell me how to do this please?

Answer (score 2):

On the main menu:

*Settings > System > Storage*